# Explicación detallada de como funciona este bucle

Tags: javascript, array, bucle-for

estoy tratando de hacer un juego sencillo en Javascript siguiendo los pasos de esta pagina https://developer.mozilla.org en concreto voy por el sexto paso (https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Games/Workflows/Famoso_juego_2D_usando_JavaScript_puro/Construye_grupo_bloques) donde después de declarar una serie de variables se crea un array bidimensional y un bucle con el que se recorre, en concreto el código es este:

```
var bricks = [];
 for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
     bricks[c] = [];  // <-- sobre todo no entiendo esta parte
 for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
    bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0 }; // <-- ni esta 
     }
 }
```

y mi pregunta es si alguien me podría explicar detalladamente como funciona este bucle anidado junto al array ya que no lo termino de entender del todo.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: la línea `bricks[c] = []` crea un arreglo para cada columna (estas serán las filas). la línea `bricks[c][r] = {x:0, y:0}` crea los ladrillos, y les da una posición inicial en `(0,0)`. Esto se hace así porque javascript no tiene una forma de declarar arreglos n-dimensionales como en algunos otros lenguajes (Java, C#, etc)

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda. Un saludo.

Comment: como te digo, javascript no tiene una forma de declarar arreglos n-dimensionales, así que generalmente uno define primero las columnas y luego las filas, o al revés, filas - columnas , todo dependerá de ti. Nota que en este caso al hacer `bricks[x][y]` `x` es la columna y  `y` es la fila, esto es lo contrario que sucede en muchos lenguajes donde el primer entero hace referencia a la fila, y el segundo a la columna. Como te digo, esto es trivial y depende del programador ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El bucle es sencillo de entender. Tienes una variable bricks que es un array ( `briks=[];` ).

Lo que hace el primer `for` es crear un array en cada posición posición del array bricks ( `briks[0]=[]; briks[1]=[]; briks[2]=[]; etc.` ). Esto hace que sea bidimensional.

Y por último el segundo `for` añade un objeto en cada posición del array bidimensional (`briks[0][0]={ x: 0, y: 0 }; briks[0][1]={ x: 0, y: 0 }; briks[0][2]={ x: 0, y: 0 }; etc.`).

Hay diferentes maneras de crear los array bidimensionales en javascript. En este caso declara los arrays auqnue no es necesario hacerlo.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que el código al que haces referencia es este:

```
var bricks = [];
for(c=0; c<brickColumnCount; c++) {
    bricks[c] = [];
    for(r=0; r<brickRowCount; r++) {
        bricks[c][r] = { x: 0, y: 0 };
    }
}
```

Para entenderlo también necesitamos las variables anteriores:

```
var brickRowCount = 3;
var brickColumnCount = 5;
var brickWidth = 75;
var brickHeight = 20;
var brickPadding = 10;
var brickOffsetTop = 30;
var brickOffsetLeft = 30;
```

La forma de trabajar de este bucle es que primero define **c** haciendo referencia a las columnas, por lo tanto indica que **c** (columnas) es **igual a 0** (**c=0**), luego le indica que realice el bucle siempre que **c** sea **menor que brickColumnCount** que anteriormente lo definimos en **5**, es decir ejecutará el bucle hasta llegar a 5 y como hace eso? pues **en cada pasada añade 1 a c** (esto se consigue con (**c++**)
Quedando algo así: for (columnas es igual a 0, ejecuto el bucle for hasta que columnas sea inferior a brickcolumncount es decir 5, con cada pasada añade 1 a columnas) {
El array **bricks** que lo hemos definido anteriormente y está vacío ahora en cada pasada de bucle contendrá la columna, es decir acabará teniendo 5 columnas.
}

Espero que te haya servido mi explicación ;)